# Как поменять название кнопки (Submit), которая генерируется автоматически ангуляром

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Используем json schema для создания формы. Ангуляр автоматически создает кнопку submit. Как поменять её название. (Используем ангуляр на тайпскрипте). Версия ангуляра - вторая. Так с кодом будет посложнее поскольку я новичок в ангуляре. Вот json schema:

```
`{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
        "type": "string"
    },

        "Objects": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "object": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "objectId": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "attributes": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "attributeId": {
                          "type": "string"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "type": "string"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
  }
}`
```

Что ещё нужно? Требуется ли добваить код компонента?

Comment: Где ваш код? Где технические подробности типа версии ангуляра?

Comment: A K можете сказать, какая ещё информация необходима?